# Unable to call my wcf endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created an endpoint through in wcf and hosted wcf through console application.

I have put a debugger on that method which I am trying to call from browser but that method is not getting called.

I have taken reference from below web sites :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731080(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.infoworld.com/article/3034606/application-development/how-to-work-with-a-wcf-service-programmatically.html

**Wcf service:**

```
public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
    {
        public double Add(double n1, double n2)
        {
            return n1 + n2;
        }
        public double Subtract(double n1, double n2)
        {
            return n1 - n2;
        }
    }

 [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICalculator
    {

        [OperationContract]
        double Add(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Subtract(double n1, double n2);
    }
```

**Console App which is hosting wcf application:**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serviceUrl = "http://localhost:56264/CalculatorService.svc";
            var uri = new Uri(serviceUrl);
            ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), uri);
            try
            {
                BasicHttpBinding binding1 = new BasicHttpBinding();
                selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), binding1, "CalculatorService");
                selfHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Service started... " + serviceUrl);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

When I try to call my wcf service endpoint like below then I am getting below result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Operation Contract should have WebGet() attribute.

```
 [WebGet()]
 [OperationContract]
 double Add(double n1, double n2);
```